# Populate multiple Textbox from Database by select Dropdown list ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have to get multiple columns of data from the database using Ajax. When I select the dropdown list then the parameter will pass in Ajax to the controller to get all values and show in different textboxes.
I can get only 1 column but can not get all columns.
Please help me to solve the problem. My sample codes are below.
Thanks

Ajax Script

```
<script>
function getUploadedFile(Sle) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Privacy/GetUploadfileName",
        data: { "FileID": Sle.value },
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#uploadedFile1").val(data);                
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Model

```
public class Semester
{        
    public int SemesterNo { get; set; }
    public string SemesterId { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{        
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public string SemesterNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        ViewBag.semester = new SelectList(_context.Semester, "SemesterNo", "SemesterId");
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult GetUploadfileName(string FileID)
    {
        //get the filename result accoding to ID
        var result = _context.Courses.Where(x => x.SemesterNumber == FileID).First();
        return Ok(result.CourseID);
    }
```

Views

```
@model MVCInsertDB.Models.Course
<form method="post" asp-controller="Privacy" asp-action="Privacy" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Semester</label>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SemesterNumber, ViewBag.semester as SelectList, "--Select Item--", new { id = "uploadedFile", @class = "js-select u-select--v1-select w-10", @onChange = "getUploadedFile(this)" })
</div>
<br />
<label>Course Id</label>
<input id="uploadedFile2" type="text" class="form-control" />
<br />
<label>Course Name</label>
<input id="uploadedFile3" type="text" class="form-control" />
<br />
<label>Course Credit</label>
<input id="uploadedFile4" type="text" class="form-control" />
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the Course model's all properties value in the  with the div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try directly return a jsonresult from MVC controller and modify the ajax to receive the json response.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

AJax:

```
        function getUploadedFile(Sle) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetUploadfileName",
                data: { "FileID" : Sle.value },
                type: "Post",
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#uploadedFile2").val(data.courseID);
                    $("#uploadedFile3").val(data.title);
                    $("#uploadedFile4").val(data.credits);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetUploadfileName(string FileID)
    {
        //get the filename result accoding to ID
        var result = _context.Courses.Where(x => x.SemesterNumber == FileID).First();
         return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried this but some the parameter pass null value instead of selected dropdown item. Can not find why.

Comment: What you mean about some the parameter pass null value? Do you mean some dropdown item is passed to the backend and some are not?

Comment: Sorry. Actually the data: { "FileID": Sle.value } in Ajax sending null value.

Comment: If you used `{ "FileID": Sle.value }`, you should set the   contentType to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` and then it will work well. See my update ajax codes.

Comment: Could you please share the details error ? Besides, I suggest you could try to use F12 develop tool's network tab to see what the response the server has returned.

Comment: It is working. I do not know why but now it is working.